# Use Vulkan VkImage as a CUDA cuArray

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, vulkan, cuda-arrays

What is the correct way of using a Vulkan VkImage as a CUDA cuArray?

I've been trying to follow some examples, however I get a CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE on a call to `cuExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray()`

To provide the information in an ordered way.

I'm using CUDA 10.1

Base code comes from https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan, in particular I'm using the [01 - Vulkan Gears](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan#01---vulkan-gears) demo, enriched with the saveScreenshot method [09 - Capturing screenshots](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan#09---capturing-screenshots)

Instead of saving the snapshot image to a file, I'll be sending the snapshot image into CUDA as a CUarray.

I've enabled the following instance and device extensions:

```cpp
        std::vector<const char*> instanceExtensions = {
                VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME,
                VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME,
                VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_CAPABILITIES_EXTENSION_NAME,
                VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_SEMAPHORE_CAPABILITIES_EXTENSION_NAME };

        std::vector<const char*> deviceExtensions = { VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_EXTENSION_NAME,
                VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_FD_EXTENSION_NAME,
                VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_SEMAPHORE_EXTENSION_NAME,
                VK_KHR_EXTERNAL_SEMAPHORE_FD_EXTENSION_NAME };
```

I have a VkImage, created as follows:

```cpp
        // Create the linear tiled destination image to copy to and to read the memory from
        VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateCI(vks::initializers::imageCreateInfo());
        imageCreateCI.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
        // Note that vkCmdBlitImage (if supported) will also do format conversions if the swapchain color format would differ
        imageCreateCI.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        imageCreateCI.extent.width = width;
        imageCreateCI.extent.height = height;
        imageCreateCI.extent.depth = 1;
        imageCreateCI.arrayLayers = 1;
        imageCreateCI.mipLevels = 1;
        imageCreateCI.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
        imageCreateCI.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
        imageCreateCI.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;
        imageCreateCI.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
        imageCreateCI.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT;

        VkExternalMemoryImageCreateInfoKHR extImageCreateInfo = {};

        /*
         * Indicate that the memory backing this image will be exported in an
         * fd. In some implementations, this may affect the call to
         * GetImageMemoryRequirements() with this image.
         */
        extImageCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
        extImageCreateInfo.handleTypes |= VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_FD_BIT_KHR;

        imageCreateCI.pNext = &extImageCreateInfo;

        // Create the image
        VkImage dstImage;
        VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkCreateImage(device, &imageCreateCI, nullptr, &dstImage));
        // Create memory to back up the image
        VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
        VkMemoryAllocateInfo memAllocInfo(vks::initializers::memoryAllocateInfo());
        VkDeviceMemory dstImageMemory;
        vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, dstImage, &memRequirements);
        memAllocInfo.allocationSize = memRequirements.size;
        // Memory must be host visible to copy from
        memAllocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = vulkanDevice->getMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);

        VkExportMemoryAllocateInfoKHR exportInfo = {};
        exportInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_EXPORT_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO_KHR;
        exportInfo.handleTypes = VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_FD_BIT_KHR;

        memAllocInfo.pNext = &exportInfo;


        VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkAllocateMemory(device, &memAllocInfo, nullptr, &dstImageMemory));
        VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkBindImageMemory(device, dstImage, dstImageMemory, 0));
```

From there I'll:

Get the Vulkan Memory Handler:

```cpp
int CuEncoderImpl::getVulkanMemoryHandle(VkDevice device,
        VkDeviceMemory memory) {
    // Get handle to memory of the VkImage

    int fd = -1;
    VkMemoryGetFdInfoKHR fdInfo = { };
    fdInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_GET_FD_INFO_KHR;
    fdInfo.memory = memory;
    fdInfo.handleType = VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_FD_BIT_KHR;

    auto func = (PFN_vkGetMemoryFdKHR) vkGetDeviceProcAddr(device,
            "vkGetMemoryFdKHR");

    if (!func) {
        printf("Failed to locate function vkGetMemoryFdKHR\n");
        return -1;
    }

    VkResult r = func(device, &fdInfo, &fd);
    if (r != VK_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Failed executing vkGetMemoryFdKHR [%d]\n", r);
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;

}
```

Import the memory:

```cpp
    CUDA_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_DESC memDesc = { };
    memDesc.type = CU_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_FD;
    memDesc.handle.fd = getVulkanMemoryHandle(device, memory);
    memDesc.size = extent.width*extent.height*4;

    CUDA_DRVAPI_CALL(cuImportExternalMemory(&externalMem, &memDesc));
```

And map the memory: This is the step that it is failing.

```
CUarray CuEncoderImpl::getCUDAArrayFromExternalMemory(const VkExtent3D &extent,const CUexternalMemory &m_extMem) {
    CUmipmappedArray m_mipmapArray;
    CUresult result = CUDA_SUCCESS;
    CUarray array;

    CUDA_ARRAY3D_DESCRIPTOR arrayDesc = { };
    arrayDesc.Width = extent.width;
    arrayDesc.Height = extent.height;
    arrayDesc.Depth = 0;
    arrayDesc.Format = CU_AD_FORMAT_UNSIGNED_INT32;
    arrayDesc.NumChannels = 4;
    arrayDesc.Flags = CUDA_ARRAY3D_SURFACE_LDST;

    CUDA_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_MIPMAPPED_ARRAY_DESC mipmapArrayDesc = { };
    mipmapArrayDesc.arrayDesc = arrayDesc;
    mipmapArrayDesc.numLevels = 1;
    mipmapArrayDesc.offset = 0;

    CUDA_DRVAPI_CALL(cuExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray(&m_mipmapArray, m_extMem, &mipmapArrayDesc));

    CUDA_DRVAPI_CALL(cuMipmappedArrayGetLevel(&array, m_mipmapArray, 0));
    return array;
}
```

I've been trying multiple combinations of the parameters, but failed so far. The error point to an invalid parameter, but I'm not sure how to find what's wrong.

Only thing that had worked is to map the Vulkan image memory to a host buffer and then copying it into the CUDA array... but I guess that's expensive and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @talonmies Vulkan-CUDA interoperability is a feature of CUDA 10, see https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-10-features-revealed/

Answer (score 14):

For the record, I finally got this to work.

Some notes and the modifications I had to do to the code listed in the question:

1. Vulkan-CUDA interoperability is advertised as a feature of CUDA 10, see [CUDA 10 Features revealed](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-10-features-revealed/)
2. The tiling of the image that is going to be mapped had to be `VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL

```cpp
        imageCreateCI.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
```

3. The memory for that image must be allocated with the `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT`

```cpp
        memAllocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = vulkanDevice->getMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
```

4. The memory descriptor when importing the memory should use the memory size that was returned in the memory requirements (`size` below is `memRequirements.size` from the code creating the image):

```cpp
    CUDA_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_DESC memDesc = { };
    memDesc.type = CU_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_FD;
    memDesc.handle.fd = getVulkanMemoryHandle(device, memory);
    memDesc.size = size;

    CUDA_DRVAPI_CALL(cuImportExternalMemory(&externalMem, &memDesc));
```

5. Finally the mapped array is described as being `CU_AD_FORMAT_UNSIGNED_INT8` with four channels and with a `CUDA_ARRAY3D_COLOR_ATTACHMENT`

```cpp
    CUDA_ARRAY3D_DESCRIPTOR arrayDesc = { };
    arrayDesc.Width = extent.width;
    arrayDesc.Height = extent.height;
    arrayDesc.Depth = 0;
    arrayDesc.Format = CU_AD_FORMAT_UNSIGNED_INT8;
    arrayDesc.NumChannels = 4;
    arrayDesc.Flags = CUDA_ARRAY3D_COLOR_ATTACHMENT;

    CUDA_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_MIPMAPPED_ARRAY_DESC mipmapArrayDesc = { };
    mipmapArrayDesc.arrayDesc = arrayDesc;
    mipmapArrayDesc.numLevels = 1;
    mipmapArrayDesc.offset = 0;

    CUDA_DRVAPI_CALL(cuExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray(&m_mipmapArray, m_extMem, &mipmapArrayDesc));
```

After those changes, I was able to get it to work. 
I few the changes were glaring mistakes on my side (like the size), a few things I found carefully re-reading the documentation for the 100th time, others were guesses at hints in the documentation and, finally, a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Many thanks to you, I managed to run that in less than a day :)

Comment: Though, I am not sure about one thing. Which destruction/deallocation functions we must call in this pipeline? I guess,  cudaFreeMipmappedArray and cudaDestroyExternalMemory, but not cudaFreeArray on a mipmap level?